# how to remove empty row and column from handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Handsontable, In my application on button (Table Editor) click, I have open (TableEditor.html) the handsontable with initially 10 rows and 10 columns and it may happen that user may use some of row and column and remaining are left empty, using my code it gives empty cells too :( , I want to delete the empty rows and column from  handsontable after clicking on button 'load' and before loading it in json?
My code is as follows :

TableEditor.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="hot"></div>
    <input type="button" name="load" id="load" value="Load">

    <script>
    var data = [[]];

              var container = document.getElementById('hot');
              var hot = new Handsontable(container,
                {
                  data: data,
                  rowHeaders: true,
                  colHeaders: true,
                  minSpareRows: 0,
                  colHeaders: true,
                  contextMenu: true,
                  minRows: 10,
                  minCols:10,  
                  mergeCells: true,
                  contextMenu: true,
                  removeRowPlugin: true

                }); 


               Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(load, 'click', function() {


                   for(var i=0; i<hot.countRows();i++)
                   {
                      //alert('Done...'+hot.isEmptyRow(i)+'-- '+i);
                       if(hot.isEmptyRow(i))
                       {
                           hot.alter('remove_row', i); 
                           //alert('Removed...'+i);
                       }
                   }  
                    for(var j=0; j<=hot.countCols();j++)
                   {
                        alert('Done...'+hot.isEmptyCol(j)+'-- '+j);
                       if(hot.isEmptyCol(j))
                       {
                           hot.alter('remove_col', j) ; 
                           alert('Removed...'+j);
                       }
                   }  


                  $.ajax('json/save.json', 'GET', JSON.stringify({"data": hot.getData()}), function (res) {
                      alert('Done...');
                    var response = JSON.parse(res.response);
                    alert('Done...');
                    if (response.result === 'ok') {
                      alert('Data saved');
                    }
                    else {
                      alert('Save error');
                    }
                  });
                }); 



    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It gives data like :

b,c,,,,,,,,,c,b,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
var gridData = hot1.getData();
var cleanedGridData = {};

$.each( gridData, function( rowKey, object) {
    if (!hot1.isEmptyRow(rowKey)) cleanedGridData[rowKey] = object;
});
```

Comment: -1 Not only you copy pasted from handsontable issues/solutions ( https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1271) but it's the wrong solution. OP is asking about reducing columns while what you pasted is about rows.